# UI5 screen size dependent properties of XML

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

Is it possible in UI5 to get any behavior like screen size dependent properties for xml?

I got a table with a few columns:

```
<table>
   <columns>
       <column id="column1">
       </column>
       <column id="column2" hAlign="Begin">
       </column>
       <column id="column3" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
       </column>
   <columns>
[...]
</table>
```

The alignment of content for `column 2` is left (`hAlign="Begin"`). But on smartphone, where `column3` is not visible due to the `minScreenWidth="Tablet"` it looks not very well. So what I want to do is changing the property of column2 to `hAlign="End"` when viewed on smartphone. How can I achieve this?

I added following line of Code to my controller:
`sap.ui.Device.media.attachHandler(this.fnSizeChange, null, sap.ui.Device.media.RANGESETS.SAP_STANDARD);`

But in the method fnSizeChange I am unable to retrieve the View..
`this.byId("column");` ends in an error 'byId is not a function' because this does not refer to something named 'window'. Also `this.getView().byId("column");` is not working.

```
fnSizeChange: function (mParams){
    switch(mParams.name){
        case "Phone":
            this.byId("column").setHAlign("End");  // NOT working
            this.getView().byId("column").setHAlign("End"); //NOT working either
            break;
        case "Tablet":
            this.byId("column").setHAlign("Begin");
            break;
        case "Desktop":
            this.byId("column").setHAlign("Begin");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this now by adding an event hangler for `sap.ui.Device.media`in my onInit function like this:

```
sap.ui.Device.media.attachHandler(
    this.reactResponsive,
    this,
    sap.ui.Device.media.RANGESETS.SAP_STANDARD
);
```

The problem was that I could not get the right context in the event handler. This was because I did not pass `this` as second parameter in the `attachHandler()` method.

After changing this I could access the whole thing without problems:

```
reactResponsive: function (oEvent) {
    switch (oEvent.name) {
        case "Phone":
            this.byId("crit").setHAlign("End");
            this.getView().byId("crit").setHAlign("End");
            break;
        case "Tablet":
            this.byId("crit").setHAlign("Begin");
            break;
        case "Desktop":
            this.byId("crit").setHAlign("Begin");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use device dependent attributes and expression binding https://help.sap.com/saphelp_ewm94/helpdata/de/8d/bd35e1577b445d8077b2bc6ad8b958/frameset.htm
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/c98d57347ba444c6945f596584d2db45.html

```
<table>
   <columns>
       <column id="column1">
       </column>
       <column id="column2" hAlign="{= ${device>/system/phone} === true ? 'End' : 'Begin' }">
       </column>
       <column id="column3" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
       </column>
   <columns>
[...]
</table>
```

or formatter function (view):

```
<table>
   <columns>
       <column id="column1">
       </column>
       <column id="column2" hAlign="{
                    path: '',
                    formatter: '.formatter.yourFormatter'
                }">
       </column>
       <column id="column3" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
       </column>
   <columns>
[...]
</table>
```

formatter.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/Device",
], function (Device) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        yourFormatter: function (sValue) {
            console.log(Device);
            var sReturn = "";
            switch (Device.system) {
            case "phone": // desktop, phone, tablet, combi
                sReturn = "sap.ui.core.HorizontalAlign.End"; // maybe only "End" not sure right now
                break;
            default:
                sReturn = "sap.ui.core.HorizontalAlign.Begin"; // maybe only "Begin" not sure right now
                break;
            }
            return sReturn;
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: Hey zYrEx,
thank you, works like a charme if screen width is not changed on run time. But how is this possible with dynamic screen?

Edit: Added my Javascript function in question!

Comment: Hi @omyholw I think you should check this: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_ewm94/helpdata/de/8d/bd35e1577b445d8077b2bc6ad8b958/frameset.htm --> I think resizing the screen size changes a break point, maybe device thinks on resizing that its phone. 
Maybe at the end you need formatter function.. :) 
please accept the answer.

Comment: btw. you shouldnt get an answer change your question and ask another thing, thats not how its working here. please accept the answer.

Comment: Hey @zYrEx, would You mind checking the function in the answer? I was able to get elements/objects with this.byId() or this.getView().byId() everytime. but not in the event handler. I can't manage to get it to work..

Comment: the function should only return a value. a formatter function cant use this-reference or switch element attributes directly. ill adapt my answer, trying my best ;)

Comment: it's not a formatter function, but an event handler.. I attached it in my onInit function with `sap.ui.Device.media.attachHandler(this.fnSizeChange, null, sap.ui.Device.media.RANGESETS.SAP_STANDARD);`. But I will continue trying.. Thank You :)

Comment: you should try using onAfterRendering function if you try to change a view element (like this.byId("column").setHAlign("Begin");)... onInit is too "early"... when using onAfterRendering all elements are already generated. But its a bit dirty to be honest!

Comment: if you are interested in my solution. I provided it as another answer. Problem was the missing context `null` as second parameter. The declaration in `onInit`is better in my opinion because the method gets also executed when the app is executed. Thank You for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it by setting **device model**

**XML view**

```
<Table>
  <columns>
    <Column hAlign="{device>/isPhone}">
      <Text text="Amount" />
    </Column>
```

**Controller**

```
onInit: function() {
    // set device model
    var oDeviceModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({ 
      'isPhone' : (sap.ui.Device.system.phone) ? "End" : "Begin"
    });
    oDeviceModel.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");
    this.getView().setModel(oDeviceModel, "device");
},
```

You can add complete **device** properties to the model, make the changes as per your requirement.